# ERROR: function st_orientedenvelope(unknown) does not exist

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I tried the example for `ST_OrientedEnvelope` given in [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_OrientedEnvelope.html) website but that failed. This function is failing for my table `geometry` column also.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_OrientedEnvelope('MULTIPOINT ((0 0), (-1 -1), (3 2))'));
```

Getting the error - `ERROR:  function st_orientedenvelope(unknown) does not exist`.

`Postgis` version - 2.5.1

What could be a possible reason?

Comment: Works for me with PostGIS 2.5. However, that the function accepts WKT as such feels odd.  Perhaps it was an unintented featere that is fixed in the later release. Try `SELECT ST_AsText(ST_OrientedEnvelope(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT ((0 0), (-1 -1), (3 2))')));`

Comment: POLYGON((3 2,2.88 2.16,-1.12 -0.84,-1 -1,3 2))